# Apprequest received on Facebook Desktop website but not on m.facebook.com (mobile)

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-app-requests

My question is very simple:

Is it "normal" that I can't receive/detect any apprequest sent from my own app on the mobile Facebook website: **m.facebook.com**. (on my Iphone for instance)

I'm pointing out that I have the Canvas URL well configured and the whole should work since I can receive them on **facebook.com** (desktop website).

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the same problem and I just fixed it.

1. Under your facebook app settings, set up your website in both Site URL and Mobile Site URL
2. Under App Details, Set Website-Mobile to Yes

Hope it can help!